# django HttpResponseRedirect is not redirecting

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, django-forms

I am opening a django form using jquery dialog, and after the submission of the form I am redirecting it to a different view. Instead of redirecting it in browser, the redirected url is getting printed in browser console.

my return statement is `return HttpResponseRedirect('q/submitted_question_edit?q_id='+str(q.id))`

the view to which it is redirected is

```
def submitted_question_edit(request):
  q_id=request.GET['q_id']
  q_record = Questions.objects.get(id=q_id)
  form = QuestionForm(instance=q_record)
  return render(request, 'question/submitted_question_edit.html', {'submitted_question_form': form})
```

my jquery success function after form submission is

```
        function successQuestionPost(data){
        $('#question_form').dialog('close');
                console.log(data);
                // reset the question form
                $("#id_title").val('');
                CKEDITOR.instances.id_question.setData('');
                $("#id_tags").val('');
                }
```

question_form is the name of the form and I am submitting it with jquery ajax. I think it is not redirecting properly because of jquery dialog. please help.

Comment: do you get any error or anything?

Comment: No error while redirecting

Comment: Are you summiting the form with an ajax request?

Comment: Yes submitting with Ajax request

Comment: @AlesMaticic thanks for pointing in the right direction, the issue is with ajax submit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using ajax to submit the form and this was causing the problem, I was using below jquery to submit the form with ajax

```
$("#question_form").on("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // moving textarea content to hidden content
        // $("#question_hidden").attr('value', $("#id_question").val());
        console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
        $.ajax( {
        type: 'GET',
        url:"http://localhost:8000/q/",
        // data:$('.q_id_c'),
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        success: successQuestionPost,
        dataType: 'html'
        });
```

});

I removed it and httpredirectresponse works now as expected.